# How to customize Jackson type information mechanism

Tags: json, jackson

In Jackson, I am using annotation **@JsonTypeInfo** to include polymorphism support.

If, I do not want to go with annotation based approach, I can use global default typing or override the type information handling module.

I have tried global type information but it is emitting type information for all non final type.

What I need ,

1. I want to include type information only for polymorphic type.
2. I want to change default format of type info (to key-value pair)

Is it possible to achieve above two points just by twitting global configuration?

If not, what extension point should I used used to customize type-information module ? 
I have read **JacksonAnnotationIntrospector** is the class which deals with type info.

Should I customize it to achieve above mentioned two points?

Help with Example will be well and good.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Jackson's `DefaultTypeResolverBuilder` for this purpose. Extend this class and override the `useForType` method appropriately. Here is an example that adds type information only for the classes belonging to the `test.jackson` package (and sub-packages):

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping;

public class CustomTypeResolverBuilder extends DefaultTypeResolverBuilder
{
    public CustomTypeResolverBuilder()
    {
        super(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean useForType(JavaType t)
    {
        if (t.getRawClass().getName().startsWith("test.jackson")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, consider that you have `Foo.java` in `test.jackson` package and `Bar.java` in `org.myorg` package, each containing an `int` variable called "integer" and a `String` variable called "string".

You can serialize objects of these two classes this way:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

TypeResolverBuilder<?> typeResolver = new CustomTypeResolverBuilder();
typeResolver.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
typeResolver.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
typeResolver.typeProperty("@CLASS");
objectMapper.setDefaultTyping(typeResolver);

Foo foo = new Foo(10, "Foo");
Bar bar = new Bar(20, "Bar");

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo));
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bar));
```

The corresponding output will be:

```
{"@CLASS":"test.jackson.Foo","integer":10,"string":"Foo"}
{"integer":20,"string":"Bar"}
```

You can also customize the name of the attribute that represents the type ("@CLASS" in the above example). Hope this helps!

Comment: [JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization · FasterXML/jackson-docs Wiki](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Moonwlker](https://github.com/bertilmuth/moonwlker) library.

With it, you can create an `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

 MoonwlkerModule module =
   MoonwlkerModule.builder()
     .fromProperty("@CLASS").toSubclassesOf(Animal.class)
     .build();

 objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

And then use that mapper to (de)serialize. The Moonwlker website contains more details and configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() {{
    this.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    this.setVisibility(this.getSerializationConfig()
            .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
    this.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    this.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN);
    this.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    this.enable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);
    this.addMixIn(Throwable.class, ThrowableMixIn.class);
    TypeResolverBuilder<?> mapTyper = new DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL) {
        public boolean useForType(JavaType t) {
            switch (_appliesFor) {
                case NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS:
                    while (t.isArrayType()) {
                        t = t.getContentType();
                    }
                    // fall through
                case OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE:
                    return (t.getRawClass() == Object.class) || !t.isConcrete();
                case NON_FINAL:
                    while (t.isArrayType()) {
                        t = t.getContentType();
                    }
                    // to fix problem with wrong long to int conversion
                    if (t.getRawClass() == Long.class) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (t.getRawClass() == XMLGregorianCalendar.class) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return !t.isFinal(); // includes Object.class
                default:
                    // case JAVA_LANG_OBJECT:
                    return t.getRawClass() == Object.class;
            }
        }
    };
    mapTyper.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
    mapTyper.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    this.setDefaultTyping(mapTyper);
}};

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,
        getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY,
        setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public static class ThrowableMixIn {

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).