# Jackson - Custom TypeId Resolver

Tags: java, jackson

I've been using a custom typeId resolver for one of my classes, so far I've been leaning on the annotation support:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "@type")
@JsonTypeIdResolver(ColumnDefinitionTypeResolver.class)
```

But now I need to customize the creation of the type resolver by passing some other dependencies to it via constructor or setters, and since Jackson is the one who instantiate it I can't find a way around it.

Is there a way to configure the ObjectMapper to use a TypeIdResolver instead of relying on annotations?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have two options:

1) If you're set on using the `@JsonTypeIdResolver` your stuck using `static` state in your `TypeIdResolver`.  This probably isn't what you want.

The default `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` will try to create an instance of the type you provide using `JsonTypeIdResolver` per its default constructor.  There is currently no way to configure it to do otherwise.

```
public final class ColumnDefinitionTypeResolver implements TypeIdResolver {
  // You could rely on static state.
  public static String SOME_ACCESSIBLE_OBJECT = null;

  public ColumnDefinitionTypeResolver() {
    // This is what gets called.
  }
}

ColumnDefinitionTypeResolver.SOME_ACCESSIBLE_OBJECT = "I can affect the implementation from here, but using static state ... be careful";
```

2) Is create a module to handle deserialization of your type and subtypes.

```
SimpleModule columnDefinitionModule = new SimpleModule("colDefMod", new Version(1, 0, 0, null))
      .addDeserializer(ColumnDefinition.class, new JsonDeserializer() {
           @Override
           public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,  JsonProcessingException {
                // Need to read the type out and then use ObjectMapper to deserialize using the correct token
            }
        })
        .registerSubtypes(...); // add your subtypes here.

(new ObjectMapper()).registerModule(columnDefinitionModule);
```

For more detailed examples, see Jackson documentation [How-To: Custom Deserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers).

Comment: "There is currently no way to configure it to do otherwise."... now in 2022 there is a way... you can provide your own `HandlerInstantiator` to create or provide the `TypeIdResolver`

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a custom type id resolver programmatically. Look at the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353774/how-to-customize-jackson-type-information-mechanism).
Look for this line:

```
typeResolver.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
```

Replace `null` with your type id resolver.