# jackson polymorphic deserialization with a custom criteria

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I need to know whether I can deserialize a generic object to it's defining type without having an additional property or without mentioning the type in an annotation.

Ex:-

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
```

In above I have to mention the `@class` property, and another way is

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
 @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog"),
 @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat")
})
```

in the above example, we are defining the subclasses and a custom type.

Using a custome deserializer `StdDeserializer<T>`

Is there any other way to do this please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can figure out a way to determine the object subtype from the JSON data, you could write a custom TypeId resolver to handle it for you. See [Jackson Custom TypeId Resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814664/jackson-custom-typeid-resolver).