# java jackson keep type information after serialize if variable of type Object

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

**ClassA**

```
public class ClassA {
   private String id;
   private Object rawData;
}
```

**ClassB**

```
public class ClassB {
   private String name;
}
```

**ClassC**

```
public class ClassC {
   String address;
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainExample {
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(  );

      ClassB classB = new ClassB();
      //ClassC classC = new ClassC();
      ClassA classA = new ClassA();
      classA.setRawData(  classB );
      //classA.setRawData(  classC );

      if (classA.getRawData() instanceof ClassB) {
         System.out.println("true ");
      } else {
         System.out.println("false");
      }

      String classAString = mapper.writeValueAsString( classA );
      ClassA a = mapper.readValue( classAString, ClassA.class );

      if (a.getRawData() instanceof ClassB) {
         System.out.println("true ");
      } else {
         System.out.println("false");
      }
   }
}
```

why first if-else printing **"TRUE"** and second if-else printing **"false"**??

How can I check the type of rawData?

Comment: look at what `classAString` is, there is no more information regarding the type of `rawData` in it. And since you omit any type information on the java side as well (since you use `Object`) it is impossible for the mapper to map to a `ClassB` - why would / should it? There is no reason for it to create an instance of that type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mapper.writeValueAsString(classA)` will serialise the instance into something similar to `{"rawData":{}}`.

While deserialising `{}` the default mapper would fail, because it treats `{}` as a non-serializable type. If you've configured `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` to `false` before, you will have an empty `Object` created.

You might want to use `mapper.enableDefaultTyping();` to include type information in JSON, and thereby deserialize into the correct types.

> NOTE: use of Default Typing can be a potential security risk if incoming content comes from untrusted sources, and it is recommended that this is either not done, or, if enabled, use `setDefaultTyping` passing a custom `TypeResolverBuilder` implementation that white-lists legal types to use.

Comment: thanks for highlighting risk. If you provide an example for TypeResolverBuilder it will be great. Is it fine to use setDefaultTyping without TypeResolverBuilder if the source is trusted (both sender and receiver belongs to same company)?

Comment: @PratapA.K: here's an example of `CustomTypeResolverBuilder `: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353774/how-to-customize-jackson-type-information-mechanism Yes, It's fine if the sources are safe.

Comment: @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property="@class")
private Object rawData; 

.........below also working. Is both are same?

Comment: @PratapA.K AFAIK, these annotations will be compound into `TypeResolverBuilder` for you

Comment: @PratapA.K but if you enable "default typing", it will override annotation behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

We can also use @JsonTypeInfo from jackson library to keep class information

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

public class ClassA {

   private String id;

   @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property="@class")
   private Object rawData;
}
```

then both if-else prints **"True"**.